# "Server Error - Can't connect to the server: unsupported URL" received on iOS mobile App

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, experience-cloud, community-cloud

I'm not a programmer but Salesforce suggested I post this question here and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

We have the same **iOS** mobile app and **Android** app for our Experience Cloud, it has a phone number on the homepage and when you tap on it, it should launch the native Phone App to dial the number.  However currently it displays this error message:

"***Server Error - Can't connect to the server: unsupported URL***"

This works as expected when clicked in a browser on both a mobile device and also a desktop.

What should we check in the **Salesforce Mobile SDK** which could be preventing the Phone App from launching?

TIA
Ellen

Answer (score 0):

You would receive this error if you are having issues with your data or internet connection, especially with certain WiFi connections.

Try turning the Airplane mode on, then off, to help reset your connection.
Additionally, you can turn off WiFi to force the use of the Cellular data if using a phone with active cellular data.

Also please make sure you're on the latest and stable ios version(15.4.1).

Comment: Thanks Rajeev for the suggestion. I tried that and the issue still occurs whether on WIFI or Cellular.  I am on iOS 15.4.1

Answer (score 0):

'Use Native Browser' under My Domain fixed it for me.

1. Login --> Setup
2. In global search enter 'My Domain'
3. At the bottom of the page you will see both "Use Native browser for iOS/Android" checkbox, please select them and save.